# mysql - Replacing a column's values with their corresponding values from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I'm trying to write a query from a READ-ONLY DB that will basically show me the relationship between parent and child values along with some additional information from other tables.

I've got the query nearly where I want it but am struggling with replacing a few values with their corresponding names and emails

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=50057c56aeee9be5f7c1c972997ca1ca)

Basically I'm trying to reflect the Name and Email shown in the email and credentials table that corresponds with the respective AcctID shown in the current place of Parent Name and Parent Email columns. ie. "John Smith" in place of '1a2b' in Parent Name and 'test@test' instead of '1a2b' in Parent Email

I tried a case statement at first but am thinking it's probably  something with the joins I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any help guys.

Comment: Sample data and desired results in a *text* table would be really helpful.  Your existing query as *text* would also help.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind next time. Last time I did this I had someone tell me the opposite so I suppose I'll make sure to have both from this point on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join to the `credentials` and `email` tables *again* to extract the parent data:

```
select
    cr1.data                as "Parent Name",
    e1.email                as "Parent Email",
    cr.data                 as "Child Name",
    e.email                 as "Child Email",
    sum(a.amount)           as "Amount",
    (sum(a.amount)*2.5/100) as "% of Amount"

from 
    email e
join
    class c
        on e.AcctID = c.AcctID
left join
    relationship r 
        on c.AcctID = r.child
left join
    amount a
        on e.AcctID = a.AcctID
left join
    credentials cr
        on e.AcctID = cr.AcctID and cr.value = 1
left join
    credentials cr1
        on r.Parent = cr1.AcctID and cr1.value = 1
left join
    email e1
        on e1.AcctId = r.Parent
where
    c.relationship = 'child'
group by 
    cr1.data, e1.email, cr.data, e.email
order by
    cr1.data
```

Output:

```
Parent Name     Parent Email    Child Name  Child Email     Amount  % of Amount
                so@so                       add@add         10.36   0.259000
John Smith      Test@Test       Jane Smith  email@email     24.72   0.618000
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8bcefccdf70f7e13197b85661d9ba888)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you simply need to `join` the `email` table twice.  The query looks like this:

```
select r.parent as "Parent Name",
       ep.email as "Parent Email",
       cr.data as "Child Name",
       ec.email as "Child Email",
       sum(a.amount) as "Amount",
       (sum(a.amount)*2.5/100) as "% of Amount"
from class c left join
     relationship r 
     on c.AcctID = r.child left join
     email ec
     on ec.AcctId = r.child left join
     email ep
     on ep.AcctId = r.parent left join
     amount a
     on c.AcctID = a.AcctID left join
     credentials cr
     on c.AcctID = cr.AcctID and cr.value = 1
where c.relationship = 'child'
group by r.Parent, ep.email, cr.data, ec.email
order by r.Parent;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8a43196e4f9ab76504ba9879c553459) is your db<>fiddle, with the fixed query.

Note that this also fixes your `join` conditions (so nothing is joining to the `email` tables once they are brought in).  And it also simplifies the `group by` keys.